# Need to deny hotlinking on a SPECIFIC directory for ALL domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to deny access to the /media directory for all domains ( this is a multidomain site )

So far I've got:

## Prevent hotlinking

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www)?.* [NC]
RewriteRule /media/ - [NC,F,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?media/?$
RewriteRule {write here}
```

I think this will filter out the /media/ to be accessed and apply rewrite rule only when /media/ is not present

You can also do something like

```
RewriteRule ^media/ - [F]
```